# A smooth hypersurface of $\mathbb P^n$ is a point in some other projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $V \subset \mathbb P^n$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$. Then, a note I'm following says : $[V]$ is a point of $\mathbb P^{N_d-1}$ where $N_d = {n+d\choose d}$.

I'm looking for an explanation of what this means?

I'm familiar with the concept of dual projective space, but there the construction is just the Proj of the dual vector space and isn't dependent on any $d$.

Comment: An hypersurface of degree $d$ is defined by an equation $a_1 x_0^d+ a_2 x_0^{d-1}x_1+...+a_{N_d} x_n^d$ up to a scalar multiple, hence by a point $[a_1 : a_2 : ... : a_{N_d}]\in\mathbb{P}^{N_d-1}$.

Comment: @Roland that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?